# How to Await in Play Framework 2 controller action?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I try to write action to generate thumb of the picture and show to user if it's not already generated.
The problem is: generation part runs in async and show part of code runs before generation part finishes.
I'm new to Scala and Play Framework and can't make show part to wait. I've tried it like this:

```
def thumbs(profiletype: String, id: Int, filename: String, extention: String) = Action {
val content = File.getBinaryContent(pathToDir + filename + "." + extention)
content match {
  case Some(c) => Ok(c).as(File.getContentType(extention))
  case _ => val picture = Picture.getById(id)
      picture match {
        case None => NotFound("Page not found")
        case Some(p) => val rslt = Future (p.generateThumbs(pathToDir, profiletype))
          val r=rslt.map(a=>a)
          Await.ready(r, Duration(8, "second"))
            Logger.debug(pathToDir + filename + "." + extention)
            val content = File.getBinaryContent(pathToDir + filename + "." + extention)
            renderBinary(content, File.getContentType(extention))}
          }
}
```

and like this without luck

```
def thumbs(profiletype: String, id: Int, filename: String, extention: String) = Action {
val content = File.getBinaryContent(pathToDir + filename + "." + extention)
content match {
  case Some(c) => Ok(c).as(File.getContentType(extention))
  case _ => val picture = Picture.getById(id)
      picture match {
        case None => NotFound("Page not found")
        case Some(p) => val rslt = Future (p.generateThumbs(pathToDir, profiletype))
          Await.ready(rslt, Duration(8, "second"))
            Logger.debug(pathToDir + filename + "." + extention)
            val content = File.getBinaryContent(pathToDir + filename + "." + extention)
            renderBinary(content, File.getContentType(extention))}
          }
}
```

This Await doesn't work and Logger logs before p.generateThumbs completes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of generating the thumbnails asychronously and blocking while waiting until the tumbnails are generated (using `Await.ready` or`Await.result`), you could [return a `Future[Result]`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaAsync).

In your case this would look like (untested):
(*I have also converted your `Option` pattern matching to a `map` and a `getOrElse` function.*)

```
def thumbs(
  profiletype: String, id: Int, filename: String, extention: String
) = Action.async { // return an (explicit) asynchronous result
  val filepath = pathToDir + filename + "." + extention
  File.getBinaryContent(filepath)
    .map ( content => 
       // we found the thumbnail, return its content as a Future[Result]
       Future.successful(Ok(content).as(File.getContentType(extention)))
    )
    .getOrElse {
      // we have not found the thumbnail, check if the Picture exists
      Picture.getById(id)
        .map { picture =>
          // we found the Picture, lets generate the thumbnails
          Future(picture.generateThumbs(pathToDir, profiletype))
            .map { futureResult =>
              // the thumbnails are created
              // return the content of the thumbnail 
              // and since we are in a Future.map this will be a Future[Result]
              Logger.debug(filepath)
              val content = File.getBinaryContent(filepath)
              renderBinary(content, File.getContentType(extention))
            }
        }
        // we could not find the Picture return a NotFound as Future[Result]
        .getOrElse(Future.successful(NotFound("Page not found")))
    }
}
```

This way we only have one blocking thread, creating the thumbnails instead of two, one creating the thumbnails and one waiting until the first thread has finished creating the thumbnails.

Play can serve other requests while the thumbnails are being created, after the thumbnails are created Play will respond with the thumbnail.

Comment: Great concepts and code to learn. Logger still logs before thumbnail creates so :( Can it be because of in picture.generateThumbs I use WS.client in async mode?

Comment: In that case you should also change the type from your `generateThumbs` to `Future[<current-type>]` and then you can change the `Future(pict.generate)` to `pict.generate` in the code above.